# Assign line from .txt file to a variable python for later use

Tags: python, function, variables, text-files

I have 2 defined functions in which both need to use a line from a text file that is found. However because they are two different functions i can't use "line" in the one which doesn't search the text file for that line. So i want to take the value of "line" which was found and assign it to a variable to use in the later functions but i get the error that "variable_Line" is not defined.

Section of first function:

```
while (len(code) == 8):
    with open('GTIN Products.txt', 'r') as search:
        for line in search:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if code in line:
                variable_Line = line #This is where i try to assign contents to a variable

                print("Your search found this result: "+line) #this prints the content of line 

                add_cart() #second function defined below
```

Second function

```
def add_cart():
    add_cart = ""
    while add_cart not in ("y", "n"):
        add_cart = input("Would you like to add this item to your cart? ")
        if add_cart == "y":
            receipt_list.append(variable_Line) #try to use the variable here but get an error

        if add_cart == "n":
            break
```

Comment: For ease of reading, I strongly suggest you don't create a local variable named `add_card` inside of a function named `add_card`.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 2):

Make `add_cart` accept an argument:

```
def add_cart(variable_Line):
```

You can then call it like this:

```
add_cart(variable_Line) #second function defined below
```

Comment: I see. Global works fine so is there an advantage to using this way? or a disadvantage for using global?

Comment: It makes code hard to follow, and makes the input of the function practically the whole program, while also making it non-testable. You can read more about it [here](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).